# dropdown list jquery

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu

I have an array with the following value,

[['6','Ltr'],['7','Ml']]

How can I use the array to fill a drop down list using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **DEMO 2:** http://jsbin.com/ewimo4/2

```
$(function() {
    var arr = [['6', 'Ltr'], ['7', 'Ml']];
    var html = "<select>";
    $.each(arr,function(i, item) {
        html += '<option value="' + item[0] + '">' + item[1] + '</option>';
    });
    html += "</select>";
    $('#select').html(html);
});
```

> - **DEMO :** http://jsbin.com/ewimo4

```
$(function() {
    var arr = [['6', 'Ltr'], ['7', 'Ml']];
    $.each(arr,function(i, item) {
        alert(item[0] + ' ' + item[1]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dump-large-array-into-dropdown-list).

```
var handles = [];

function populateHandles() {
   var options = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) {
      options += '<option value="' + handles[i] + '">' + handles[i] + '</option>';
   }
   $('#listBox').html(options);
}
```

Comment: please use `{}` the next time ... and you may use the link-button :)

Comment: this code is very vague ... it will not work with the code provided - instead it gives a rough overview to the logic - you may elaborate!

Comment: i`m not sure what you mean by {}